# Laravel - Disable SSL in local environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have implemented SSL in dev, test and prod environments.
I had to change some blade function to `secure_asset()` and `secure_url` for preventing Chrome to block content.
But know I have many issues in my local environment due to the changes I explained before.

Which is the way to work with SSL on server environments but not in local?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the follwing snipped to the `register()` method of one of your service providers and use the `asset()` helper instead of the `secure_asset()`. This way URLs will be forced to have the `https` scheme on environments which are not local but local environments will keep working with the unsecure `http` scheme.

```
public function register()
{
    if (config('app.env') !== 'local') {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function generate_asset_url($string)
{
    if (in_array(env('APP_ENV'), ['local', 'dev'])) {
        return asset($string);
    }
    return secure_asset($string);
}
```